# An open source PDF reader with built in dictionary or plugins?

Tags: open-source, cross-platform, pdf-viewer, translation, dictionary

I'm using Adobe Acrobat for my daily PDF reading and there are a lot of words I need to translate. Now I have to double click > copy > open browser > past > search for meaning > go back to PDF reader. This is cumbersome. I was wondering if there are any PDF readers, most preferably open source and cross platform, which has a built in dictionary (or plugin) activated by double clicking on a word?

P.S.1. I suppose some of the open source softwares suggestion [here](https://alternativeto.net/software/okular/?license=opensource) should have this feature.

P.S.2. I have also asked this question [here in reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/opensource/comments/8fya7v/an_open_source_pdf_reader_with_built_in/?st=jgm2l70s&sh=12662b5e).

Answer (score 3):

I found a [tutorial](https://youtu.be/dgfQRCuWU7c) of adding a real-time google translation button for pdf-xchange editor.
Although pdf-xchange editor is not open source software, but I think it is a good hint for other pdf viewers.

## update

You can download PDF-XChange Editor free version [here](https://www.tracker-software.com/product/pdf-xchange-editor)

Comment: Can you write here the relevant parts of said link? Along with any links to the needed downloads for the relevant software?

Answer (score 2):

A solution other than a specific PDF reader is to use an external program such as [**GoldenDict**](http://goldendict.org/). It features a so-called *”Scan Popup“*: Each time you select a word in any program—e.g. in your favourite PDF reader—a popup containing the lookup result will show up.

---

(*) trom the GoldenDict in-application help: [[source code](https://github.com/goldendict/goldendict/blob/a31dcd61415e8bf8fe17172dab1b3083019d775f/article_maker.cc#L320-L322)]

> To look up words from other active applications, you would need to
>   first activate the *"Scan popup functionality"* in
>   **Preferences**, and then enable it at any time either by
>   triggering the '[Scan] Popup' icon [in the toolbar], or by clicking the tray icon [..] with your right mouse button and choosing so in the menu
>   you've popped.

Comment: ah very nice. This is also [a similar work around with Artha](https://www.reddit.com/r/opensource/comments/8fya7v/an_open_source_pdf_reader_with_built_in/dy7eubw). GoldenDict is probably even better. Can you tell me how can activate this scane popup feature?

Comment: @Foad "Edit" > "Preferences" (F4) > "Scan Popup" tab > "Enable scan popup functionality"